# Flow onstatuschange not running on FINISH

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, aura, visual-flows

I have a screen flow that has a sub flow. On the subflow I have an Aura component that has the following line.

```xml
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.statusChange}" />
```

The statusChange method is just this

```javascript
statusChange: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log(" test ");
},
```

The statusChange method runs on the "STARTED" change but not on the "FINISHED" change. Any idea why?

I tried replacing the built in footer with a custom footer, but when running the following code it navigates the parent flow and not the subflow.

```javascript
var navigate = cmp.get('v.navigateFlow');
navigate("NEXT");
```

Comment: did you find a find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Try to include this on statusChange

```javascript
 if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
        console.log(" test ");
 }
```

and also on flow please add Finish button on footer.

Comment: The statusChange method isn't running so adding an if statement to it didn't change anything. The Next button and the Finish button are the same and it is already on the page but when I click it the Next button it doesn't run the statusChange method.